# NUnit DateTime assertion problem on jenkins

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, jenkins

i use NHibernate and Spring.net templates for creating DAO. i wrote some tests for saving and retrieving entities. Problem is all test pass on our local machines but on Jenkins there are strange problems with DateTime variables:

Message:

```
Expected: 2011-06-16 15:19:23.765
But was:  2011-06-16 15:19:23.765
```

Any clues what may be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the two dates are subtly different, in the sub-millisecond range, probably due to the storage not supporting date/time values to the "ticks" precision.

If you're really lucky, NUnit may provide an "equal within certain tolerance" for `DateTime` as it does for `double`. If not, something like this would be okay:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(oneDate.TotalSeconds - anotherDate.TotalSeconds) < 0.001)
```

Either that, or potentially round or truncate both `DateTime` values to the appropriate millisecond, and *then* use `AreEqual`. That would definitely give a more useful failure message.

Comment: Like oneDate.TotalMilliseconds vs anotherDate.TotalMilliseconds

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest solution is:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).Within(tolerance).Milliseconds);
```

After Within(tolerance) You can specify anything from Milliseconds up to days.

If you are using http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NUnit.Snippets then it's only

`atiewms tab tab`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Assert.Equals(oneDate.ToString("s"), anotherDate.ToString("s"));
```

where "s" means

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

(ISO 8601).